# sql insert of multiple rows if not exists with one value coming from a sub-query

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-insert

the following setup (SQLExpress/MS Sql Server 2005):

```
create table tb1 (keyx int, value1 int);
create table tb2 (keyx int, value2 int);
```

I'd like to insert several rows into tb2, for a list of value2s and the same keyX. keyX I should get out of a select statement like

```
select keyX from tb1 where tb1.value1 = 1234
```

EDIT: the above select statement returns 1 row (keyX and value1 are both unique)

The insert should only happen if not already existing.

Couldn't get this working with many almost/similar solutions found here and on other sites.

Last try to insert key value pairs with keyX as key and the values to be (1, 2, 3):

```
insert into tb2 (value2, keyX)
select t1.keyX from (select keyX from tb1 where value1 = 1234) as t1
values (1, t1.keyX), (2, t1.keyX), (3, t1.keyX)
where not exists (select * from tb2 as t2 where t2.keyX = t1.keyX and t2.value2 = t1.keyX)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
insert into tb2 (keyX, value2)
select t1.keyX, v.value2 
from tb1 t1
cross join ( values (1), (2), (3) ) v(value2)
where t1.value1 = 1234 and not exists (
    select 1 from tb2 t2 where t2.keyX = t1.keyX and t2.value2 = v.value2
)
```

The query selects from `tb1` with respect to `value1`, then "multiplies" the rows using a cartesian join (the syntax for the row constructor - `values` - may differ depending on the database you are running). Finally, we ensure that the rows does not already exist in the target with `not exists`.

Comment: Thanks! Using ms sql, getting the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'" (also had this several times already when trying different approaches).

Comment: By mssql you mean sql-server? The query seems to work in this database, eg in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/4WeBEqAv

Comment: Excellent link! Thank you. Actually it's SQLExpress by MS, but I thought they share their language syntax. Still got the error, will hopefully find the reason.

Comment: I read that SQLExpress is a free distribution of SQL Server so the syntax should be suppported indeed…unfortunately I don’t have such a database at hand to test, @RobinHolenweger.